# Points on the boundary of a circle

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Does there exist a circle whose boundary contains 6 points whose 15 pairwise distances are distinct integers?

Comment: Any restriction on what radius we can take for the circle?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code no

Comment: I think 4 points would already be hard/impossible, let alone 6

Comment: @IvoBeckers Do you mean "hard", or do you mean "impossible"? The distinction is quite important.

Comment: @dshin What I mean that it's either hard or impossible because I don't know it. But that's just my intuition. My gut tells me that it's unlikely to have a solution. But I'm no geometry expert and I'd love to see a solution if there is one.

Comment: As for the question: do you need integer distances between any two, or just integer lengths for any vertex on the hexagon they make within the circle?

Comment: @TimCouwelier I considered a clarifying edit to the problem statement, but I realized I do not understand your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what "pairwise" means. How many line segments would an illustration of the solution contain? 3, from connecting each point to exactly one other point? 6, from connecting each point to its neighbors on the boundary? 15, from connecting each point to each other point?

Comment: I've added the number "15" to the problem statement.

Comment: As per @TimCouwelier's comment: Do the points on the circle have to have integer coordinates?

Comment: If not, then the radius is irrelevant.

Comment: I found that 4 is possible :) check [this](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2002volume2/FG200221.pdf) . Stuff mentioned there could perhaps help with 6 too

Comment: @IvoBeckers In the case of 4 points, consider Pythagoras. Construct a 3-4-5 triangle ABC (right angle at B, BC=3), place the circle's centre in the middle of AC and draw a circle of radius 2.5 units. The circle circumscribes ABC. Construct another 3-4-5 triangle ADC in the opposite semicircle to ABC, with AD=3. Then A,B,C,D are points on a circle that are pair-wise at integer distances from each other.

Comment: @IvoBeckers You beat me to a solution for the 4-point case. :) Mine fits in a comment, though. :P

Comment: @Lawrence I think you missed the word "distinct" in the problem statement.

Comment: I have a feeling that this might've been a better fit for maths or mathoverflow, but...

Comment: @dshin Yes, that's a significantly harder problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This puzzle of mine appears to have languished with no solution for some time. I don’t remember the solution I initially had in mind, but I thought of one recently that might be of interest, so answering my own puzzle here.

It suffices to show that for any $n$, there exists an $n$-gon inscribed in the unit circle with pairwise-distinct rational distances, since any such $n$-gon can be converted to one with integer distances by a simple dilation.

We prove this by induction, starting with two diametrically opposite points $P_1$ and $P_2$. Each subsequent point can be found by picking a [primitive](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePythagoreanTriple.html) [Pythagorean triple](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html) $(a, b, c)$, and picking a point $Q$ such that the right triangle $\triangle P_1P_2Q$ has side lengths $(2a/c, 2b/c, 2)$. The induced distances to the other existing points are guaranteed to be rational thanks to [Ptolemy’s Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PtolemysTheorem.html) and the induction hypothesis. Now, some choices of Pythagorean triple might lead to distance collisions. But only finitely many choices will do so, and there are an infinite number of primitive Pythagorean triples, implying that a good choice of Pythagorean triple exists. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 22):

They do exist. And they are actually called Brahmagupta Hexagons. An example is this:

[image]

Which I took from [this paper](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2005volume5/FG200515.pdf) which has a lot more info on them

Comment: Surprising! +1 for the reference

Comment: Wow, never knew about these. The methodology in the paper seems similiar to the methodology I used to create the puzzle. However, my puzzle is different, as it contains the word "distinct". Without that word, we can actually construct a Brahmagupta Hexagon whose side lengths are $\leq5$.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a 6-gon whose 15 pairwise distances are all distinct integers, but not sure if its vertices lie on a circle.

> sides 47, 663, 264, 169, 105, 1020, diagonals 700, 884, 975, 855, 952, 1001, 425, 520, 272, and area 196950. See https://oeis.org/A270558